# Formal Definition of Cardinality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, foundations

I am a first year student. I am trying to find a precise definition of cardinal numbers. I am unable to find it anywhere. I am fine with finite cardinalities. I also know that different sets have different sizes. But how to have a precise definition of a cardinal number ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, since you have just started exploring mathematics, here is a (pretty simple) definition due to Frege.

You consider the "collection" of all sets. Put an equivalence relation on this as follows :

Sets $A$ and $B$ are equivalent iff there is a bijection $A \xrightarrow{\sim} B$.

It is an exercise to check that this is indeed an equivalence relation.

Now, a cardinal is defined to be an equivalence class under this relation. So for instance, the equivalence class containing $\{1,2,...,n\}$ is the cardinal $n$.
The class containing $\mathbb{N}$ is the cardinal Aleph-Naught.
The class containing $\mathbb{R}$ is the cardinal $c$ (continuum) and so on.

Comment: "Frige" is "Gottlob Frege"? I don't know if you misspelled the name or it's just a different way of writing it or it's a mathematician I don't know.

Comment: I'm sure it's just a typo, like "euqivalence". I fixed them both.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this (accepted) answer doesn't include any of the caveats mentioned in Wofsey's answer. Even a sentence or two, say "However, this definition doesn't work with most modern axiomatic foundations for set theory. Instead, one chooses a representative element from each equivalence class, or something along those lines."

Comment: Yester, you are right. It was merely a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Regarding Michael Weiss's comment, there's a reason I put quotes when I used the term "collection". Since the OP is in the first year of mathematical training, I chose not to speak more.

Comment: @Category_Theorist However, the equivalence classes are also proper classes, and so the definition you offer just doesn’t work in ZFC, for example, one of the most popular axiomatizations (perhaps *the* most popular).  Like I said, just a couple of sentences would have fixed the problem. To someone with a set theory background, this blemish is a serious eyesore.

Comment: What is this weird skewed arrow with a floating tilde from A to B? Is that meant to be a bijection symbol?

Answer (score 17):

While Category_Theorist's answer is a good idea to have in mind about how you could define cardinal numbers, in the standard foundations for mathematics (ZFC) there are technicalities that prevent it from working.  The problem is that the equivalence class of all sets of a given cardinality is not actually a *set*--it is a *proper class*, a collection which is too big to actually be a set.

There are various ways to circumvent this difficulty, all of which are unfortunately pretty technical if you are just starting to learn set theory.  The standard approach is to, instead of taking the equivalence class of *all* sets of a given cardinality, take one particular representative of the equivalence class.  In the context of ZFC, it turns out that there is a natural and convenient canonical representative set of each cardinality.  The idea is to restrict to sets which are *well-ordered* by the element relation $\in$.  These sets are called ordinals, and by the rigidity properties of well-orderings, the collection of ordinals themselves is well-ordered by $\in$, with each ordinal being the set of all smaller ordinals.  You can then define a cardinal number to be an ordinal which is the *least* ordinal of its cardinality.  So, for example, the cardinal number $\aleph_0$ is the least infinite ordinal (which is the set of all finite ordinals), and the cardinal number $\aleph_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal (which is the set of all countable ordinals).

This approach only captures all possible cardinalities if you know that every set can be well-ordered, so that it can be put into bijection with some ordinal.  This statement is equivalent to the axiom of choice, so if you do not assume the axiom of choice, you need a different definition for cardinals.  Here the standard approach is to fall back on the idea of taking the equivalence class of sets of a given cardinality, but instead of taking *all* sets of a given cardinality (which would form a proper class instead of a set), you take only the sets of minimal possible *rank* of that cardinality, which do form a set. (The *rank* of a set is an ordinal number that roughly captures how many steps it takes to build that set starting from the empty set.)

Comment: How can something be to big to be a set? Isn't a set just a collection of different things? And at the same time, you said that a proper class also is a collection?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: If you allow arbitrary collections to be sets then you get [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).  So the axioms of ZFC instead only allow you to construct certain collections as sets; arbitrary definable collections of sets are then called classes.

Comment: Interesting paradox! So do classes resolve it?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: The resolution is to reject the axiom that any collection is a set, and then the paradox just becomes a proof that there is no set of all sets that do not contain themselves.  "Class" is just the word used for any collection of sets you can define, even if it might not be a set.

Comment: Okay, but my point was, can’t we just create a corresponding paradox for classes, by defining a class that is the collection of all classes that don’t contain themselves, and then realizing that that means that _it also_ must contain itself if and only if doesn’t contain itself?

Comment: A class is a collection of *sets*, not classes, so there is no class of classes that don't contain themselves (only a class of sets that don't contain themselves).

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: But what if you want to collect collections in some way? Is there some other object for doing that?

Comment: You can't do that in the context of ZFC, since you can't represent classes with variables or quantify over them.  There are some other axiomatic set theories where it is possible to define collections of classes (but these collections are not themselves classes).

Comment: What do you mean I can't represent classes with variables? So if I define a class as the collections of all sets that don't contain themselves, can't I label that "A"? Isn't that a representation of that class with a variable? And what do you mean by to quantify over classes? It makes sense, though, that if you can define a collection of classes, that collection cannot itself be a class (otherwise it would have been kind of pointless to introduce classes from the first place, I guess).

Comment: In ZFC, the only things that actually *exist* in the usual sense are sets.  You can talk about classes indirectly by talking about the properties that define them (for instance, you can talk about the class of all sets that don't contain themselves by talking about the property of not containing themselves which some sets have).  But in the formal language of ZFC, all variables refer to sets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146090/discussion-between-hellogoodbye-and-eric-wofsey).

Answer (score 2):

Eric Wofsey has already given a nice answer for the precise definition of cardinal numbers, but let me point out that for most math one actually does not need these "canonical representatives", instead one can work with the cardinality *relation*, so even if we do not have a notion of cardinal number, we can say that #$\mathbb{N}$<#$\mathbb{R}$, since there is an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but no bijection.

I point this out because the formal definition of cardinal number requires some advanced set theory.

Comment: To say the same thing another way: perhaps surprisingly to new learners, defining what it means for two cardinalities to be equal or for one cardinality to be less than another is more fundamental than actually defining cardinalities themselves!